# Why does this simple std::thread example not work?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Tried the following example compiled with `g++ -std=gnu++0x t1.cpp` and `g++ -std=c++0x t1.cpp` but both of these result in the example aborting.

```
$ ./a.out 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  
Aborted
```

Here is the sample:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void doSomeWork( void )
{
    std::cout << "hello from thread..." << std::endl;
    return;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    std::thread t( doSomeWork );
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying this on Ubuntu 11.04:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2
```

Anyone knows what I've missed?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you didn't join the thread in main?

Comment: t.join() was in my example at home, but I missed it when I created the question on StackOverflow.  I've edited the sample above.

Comment: I thought it was going to be fine but I can't even get it to compile on g++ MinGW-w64! Seems I'm worse off than you. The following command proves that the declaration for std::thread doesn't get included: `g++ -pthread -std=c++11 -E  c:\temp\test.cpp>delme.txt`

Comment: *This problem happened to me when running tensorflow jobs. I waited a few minutes, ran the job again and the error faded away.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have to `join` `std::thread`s, just like you have to join `pthreads`.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    std::thread t( doSomeWork );
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:** [This Debian bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=576485) pointed me to the solution: add `-pthread` to your commandline. This is most probably a workaround until the `std::thread` code stabilizes and g++ pulls that library in when it should (or always, for C++).

Comment: Huh, I could have sworn this worked when I tested it three months ago. I just tested my own correction on Arch Linux GCC 4.6 and I get the same error. That's a bit puzzling :(

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange. I suppose it could simply be a problem with GCC itself that hasn't been worked out yet. It looks like such a simple thing should be working

Comment: I've added `-pthread` but getting same error. I use GCC 4.6 on Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Adding `-pthread` or linking against libpthread (`-lpthread`) is necessary on RHEL 6.3 with gcc 4.4.6 also.

Comment: Scratch that, I just noticed question is explicit that g++ was used.

Comment: Surely it's not strictly true that "you have to join", as you might opt instead to detach?

Comment: I observe the same problem with gcc 7.3.0 . adding -pthread does not solve the issue. In any case, I don't want to join thread, since a gui loop is running in my application on the main thread.

Comment: I am confused as to whether or not this is an actual bug with gcc 7.3.0, i wrote code similar to the one above and it was working fine before upgrading to gcc 7.3.0, and now my entire project is broken.

Answer (score 13):

Please use the pthread library during the compilation: g++ -lpthread.

Answer (score 3):

### Simplest code to reproduce that error and how to fix:

Put this in a file called s.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
void task1(std::string msg){
  cout << "task1 says: " << msg;
}
int main(){
    std::thread t1(task1, "hello");
    usleep(1000000);
    t1.detach();
}
```

Compile like this:

```
el@apollo:~/foo7$ g++ -o s s.cpp -std=c++0x
```

Run it like this, the error happens:

```
el@apollo:~/foo7$ ./s
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Operation not permitted
Aborted (core dumped)
```

To fix it, compile it like this with the -pthread flag:

```
g++ -o s s.cpp -std=c++0x -pthread
./s
```

Then it works correctly:

```
task1 says: hello
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I had **different issue** with **similar code** using [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580527/issue-with-stdthread-when-using-g-in-32-bit-mingw-4-8-0) in g++ (MinGW).  Work-around was to put some "delay" between creating a thread and joining it.

Code with infrequently failing assertion:

```
std::atomic_bool flag{false};
std::thread worker( [&] () { flag.store(true); } );
worker.join();
assert(flag.load()); // Sometimes fails
```

Work-around:

```
std::atomic_bool flag{false};
std::thread worker( [&] () { flag.store(true); } );
while (not flag.load()) { std::this_thread::yield(); }
worker.join();
assert(flag.load()); // Works fine
```

Note that `yield()` alone did not help, hence the while loop.  Using `sleep_for(...)` also works.

Answer (score -4):

You need to link to run time library

Comment: Not helpful at all.