# core dump when running simple std::thread code using gcc 4.6 and 4.7 on linux

Tags: c++, multithreading

I don't know what's wrong my simple std::thread code (listed below). It always crashes when using gcc 4.6 or the latest 4.7 on Ubuntu. I compiled it with command `g++ -std=c++11 myfile.cpp` and `g++ -std=gnu++11 myfile.cpp`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;


void func() {
    cout << "hello\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::thread thrd(func);

    thrd.join();
}
```

The callstack of the core dump is something like below

```
    #0  0x00007ffff7539445 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    #1  0x00007ffff753cbab in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    #2  0x00007ffff7b35b0d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    #3  0x00007ffff7b33c16 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    #4  0x00007ffff7b33c43 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    #5  0x00007ffff7b33e6e in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    #6  0x00007ffff7b8829c in std::__throw_system_error(int) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    #7  0x00007ffff7b89132 in std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>) ()
       from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    #8  0x000000000040118e in std::thread::thread<void (&)()> (this=0x7fffffffdeb0, __f=
        @0x400e2c: {void (void)} 0x400e2c <func()>) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/thread:133
    #9  0x0000000000400e5b in main () at main2.cpp:13
```

Comment: Probably a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485705/why-does-this-simple-stdthread-example-not-work), please test whether the solution there work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to compile using the `-pthread` option.

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -o main main.cpp
```

Comment: @Derek Glad that it worked. Note that you can accept answers by clicking on the green mark right under the vote buttons.