# Why this program throws 'std::system_error'?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this simple std::thread example not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485705/why-does-this-simple-stdthread-example-not-work)

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void f()
{
  std::cout << "hi thread" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::thread t(f);
  std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
  t.join();
}
```

Issue:

```
$ g++ -o thread_test thread_test.cpp -std=c++0x
$ ./thread_test         
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Operation not permitted
Abortado
```

"Abortado" means "aborted" in my locale.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should link it to `pthread`:

```
g++ -o thread_test thread_test.cpp -std=c++0x -lpthread
```

`libstdc++`'s `std::thread` implementation requires you to link your applications to `libpthread`, otherwise they'll throw a `std::system_error` when you try to create a thread.

Comment: Can somebody please link to a bug report or email chain or whatever where somebody justifies as to why this isn't thrown as a linker error?  How is this not a linker error that should be caught then?

Comment: @Kevin Very interesting question. I can't really find any answers online though. You might want to ask that question on a new thread, rather than just in a comment, to see if someone gives you a hint.