# Using C++11 thread with pure virtual thread function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have code where objects that are intended to execute in separate thread derive from a base class with a pure virtual `Run` function. I cannot get the following (simplified test code) to run the new thread.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void Run() = 0;
    void operator()() { Run(); }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void Run() { std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl; }
};

void ThreadTest(Base& aBase) {
    std::thread t(std::ref(aBase));
    t.join();
}

int main(/*blah*/) {
    Base* b = new Derived();
    ThreadTest(*b);
}
```

The code compiles fine (which is half the battle) but "Hello" never gets printed. If I was doing something wrong I'd expect a runtime error at some point.
I'm using gcc.

Edit: The code above fails to compile on VS2012, with:
`error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments`

You need to use a lambda instead of `std::ref`, i.e.

```
void ThreadTest(Base& aBase)
{
    std::thread t([&] ()
    {
        aBase.Run();
    });
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the STL, which never had any threading support. The std::thread class is a C++ 11 feature.

Comment: I can't reproduce this using g++ 4.7.2. Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Maybe the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485705/why-does-this-simple-stdthread-example-not-work
Try to add -pthread to g++ command line.

Comment: This works as expected on clang 3.3 with libc++.

Comment: I don't understand?  If the lib is not linked, should there not be linker errors, (there always is when I forget to link something)?

Comment: @ckarmann you were right. There was the std::system_error being thrown but it wasn't displayed on the Code::Blocks terminal. It's there when I run it from a proper terminal. Add an answer if you want the points!

Comment: Please do not change the question if you already have an accepted answer. Asks a new question if you have any questions left.

Comment: @bamboon I changed it because that code above doesn't compile on VS2012. It might have saved someone a headache

Comment: No, you replaced a totally valid code snippet with one that contains a bug. (Not calling join)

Comment: @bamboon It would have been quicker for you to add that call to `join` than delete the whole thing

Comment: No, because it changes the intent of the question. Your new code snippet doesn't compile because it has syntax errors.

Comment: @bamboon The origianl code didn't compile on VS2012. The new one fixes that

Comment: No, it contains syntax errors.

Comment: @bamboon You are right. Fixed. You know, the whole point of this site is collaboration and knowledge sharing. You could have fixed it once you spotted it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add -pthread to g++ command line, as explained in this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6485728/39622.